# Styling Windows Form Tab

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating windows Tabbed Application. Everything is good but the tabs are quiet faded and borders are very dull. I have tried changing the border style to 3D as well but no effect. Below is the screenshot

[image]

There are forums where people have suggested to use third party library to make Google Chrome type tabs. But I want the native way to get beautiful tabs.

Comment: [Painting Your Own Tabs - Second Edition](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition-2)

Answer (score 1):

You can take control of how the tabs are drawn by setting the DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed.   The example below assumes you have a TabControl named tabControl1 on the form, this will add a new tab with a blue box.

```
private Rectangle myTabRect;
        private Rectangle myInsideRect;
        private Rectangle myOutsideRect;
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TabPage tabPage1 = new TabPage();

            // Sets the tabs to be drawn by the parent window Form1.
            // OwnerDrawFixed allows access to DrawItem. 
            tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage1);
            tabControl1.Location = new Point(25, 25);
            tabControl1.Size = new Size(250, 250);
            tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;

            myTabRect = tabControl1.GetTabRect(0);
            myInsideRect = new Rectangle(tabControl1.DisplayRectangle.X -1, tabControl1.DisplayRectangle.Y -1, tabControl1.DisplayRectangle.Width + 1, tabControl1.DisplayRectangle.Height + 1);
            myOutsideRect = tabControl1.ClientRectangle;
            myOutsideRect.Width--;
            myOutsideRect.Height--;

            ClientSize = new Size(300, 500);
            Controls.Add(tabControl1);
            tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(OnDrawItem);
        }

        private void OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Draw your tab graphics here
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);
            g.DrawRectangle(p, myTabRect);

            p = new Pen(Color.Red);
            g.DrawRectangle(p, myInsideRect);

            p = new Pen(Color.Green);
            g.DrawRectangle(p, myOutsideRect);
            
        }
```

You can draw whatever style you like into the graphic context, add text, images, etc

[image]

Comment: can you please paste the image of how the tabs will look?

Comment: It doesn't look pretty, but will attach the output of the example

Comment: Update the code to draw the boxes within the render areas.